# View Pager has a mind of its own

Tags: java, android

I have a set of five panning pages in view pager. All these pages have a list view, Since the data is too much, I pre-fetch the data from the server and populate the list at position+1 itself,

For ex: When the position of the page is 0, I load the adapters with data for page 1 during page 0 itself.

The problem is, If I pan the pages slowly, the list is populated with data and displayed beautifully, if I do a fast panning, the screen gets empty with no Lists.

I tried viewpager.getadapter,notifydatasetchanged(), invalidate(), onpagechangelistener(), nothing works, I have been stuck on this small isuue for weeks, please guide me.

Comment: pastebin.com/vF2NgPdQ Code is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided a loading dialogue for the contetnts to load in between pages, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

how about caching the results into both RAM and external/internal storage , as shown in the [bitmapFun](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) example ?

also , instead of calling notifydatasetchanged on the viewpager , call it on the fragment's listView .
i don't think it's even needed.

in any case , if you wish to save the state of the fragment when you scroll between the fragments , call [setRetainInstance(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) in the onCreate method , or save&restore the state by yourself by using [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) .

about slow loading , let the loading be done concurrently (read about the [execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) command of asyncTask)  , and call cancel for the asyncTask when you leave the fragment . the behavior you are having is because asyncTasks are added in a queue manner , so you have to stop the old ones to make the new ones run .

Comment: I will try the bitmap fun example and test it, I will keep this thread updated! thank you!!